# Batch sort by column in file

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file

I wonder if there is any posibility to sort a text file by columns. For example

I have `aux1.txt` with rows like this

```
Name SecondName Grade
```

In shell i can do this

```
sort -r -k 3 aux1
```

It sorts the file by the 3rd column(grade).

In batch

```
sort /+3 < aux1.txt
```

sorts the file after the 3rd letter.

I read the sort manual for batch but no results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write your own *sort-wrapper* with a batch file.

You only need to reorder the columns into a temporary file,
sort it and order it back. (nearly obvious)

```
REM *** Get the desired colum and place it as first column in the temporary file
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%A in (aux1.txt) DO (
        set "par1=%%A"
        set "par2=%%B"
        set "par3=%%C"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!par2! !par1! !par2! !par3!
        endlocal
  )
) > aux1.txt.tmp

REM ** Now sort the first colum, but echo only the rest of the line
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims= " %%A in (`sort /r aux1.txt.tmp`) DO (
    echo(%%B
)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be too late for you but as a general advice you can do it much simpler than creating a temporary file. Just pipe it all through sort:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%x in (aux1.txt^) do @echo %%z %%x %%y^)^|sort') do echo %%b %%c %%a
```

Note, that it's a single command and can be used just by typing at command prompt without any batch file at all (have to reduce %%'s for that, of course).

Answer (score 0):

While I really like Jeb's answer, Ive been using Chris LaRosa's
[TextDB tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20220316171736/https://geocities.restorativland.org/SiliconValley/Monitor/5986/TDBUTILS.ZIP) for years.

You can sort multiple columns, pipe through another of his tools (or any other CL tool).  Kind of old...

Comment: Link not valid anymore

Comment: Its 10 years old :-)
try:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220316171736/https://geocities.restorativland.org/SiliconValley/Monitor/5986/TDBUTILS.ZIP

Answer (score 0):

`SortFileBySecondColumn.bat`

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
echo Syntax: %0 FileToSort.txt [/R]
echo /R means Sort in Reverse Order
goto Ende
)
set InputFile=%1
for /f "tokens=1-2* delims= " %%a in ('(for /f "tokens=1-2* delims= " %%n in (%InputFile%^) do @echo %%o %%n %%p^)^|sort %2') do echo %%b %%a %%c
:Ende
```

Usage: `SortFileBySecondColumn UnsortedFile.txt > SortedFile.txt`
If you exchange `delims=`  by `delims=;` then you can use it for CSV files.

Example Input file:

```
172.20.17.59 PC00000781 # 14.01.2022 12:35:55
172.20.17.22 NB00001021 # 31.01.2022 14:40:38
172.20.16.114 TRANSFER14 # 11.02.2022 11:22:07
10.59.80.27 PC00001034 # 14.02.2022 15:39:23
10.59.80.140 XXBNB00173 # 16.02.2022 10:13:31
172.20.17.23 PC00000XXX # 18.02.2022 12:40:58
10.59.232.25 NB00000178 # 18.02.2022 14:38:53
```

Resulting Output file:

```
10.59.232.25 NB00000178 # 18.02.2022 14:38:53 
172.20.17.22 NB00001021 # 31.01.2022 14:40:38 
172.20.17.59 PC00000781 # 14.01.2022 12:35:55 
172.20.17.23 PC00000XXX # 18.02.2022 12:40:58 
10.59.80.27 PC00001034 # 14.02.2022 15:39:23 
172.20.16.114 TRANSFER14 # 11.02.2022 11:22:07 
10.59.80.140 XXBNB00173 # 16.02.2022 10:13:31
```