# Sort a text file with a batch script in windows

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file

Im doing a school project where I need to sort a text file by columns chosen by the user using a batch script.

The file looks like this

```
ID Name Weight Length With Height
052 Chair 1200 100 30 2
077 Bookshelf 5000 120 30 80
096 Cabinet 15000 80 40 85
146 Cupboard 9000 80 60 200
149 Desk 3650 180 100 5
163 Mirror 25800 120 60 70
182 Table 1600 60 60 70
```

I tried copying the solution from this answer [Batch sort by column in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170964/batch-sort-by-column-in-file)

And modify it for 6 columns, code looks like this:

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /F "tokens=1-6 delims= " %%A in (%file%) DO (
        set "par1=%%A"
        set "par2=%%B"
        set "par3=%%C"
        set "par4=%%D"
        set "par5=%%E"
        set "par6=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!par3! !par1! !par2! !par3! !par4! !par5! !par6!
        endlocal
  )
) > data.txt.tmp

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims= " %%A in (`sort data.txt.tmp`) DO (
    echo(%%B
)
```

So the problems im having is that I want the top row with ID Name etc to be unchanged. Second thing is this code works when sorting by ID and Name but when I get to weight for example it dosnt sort it correctly and i get output like this:

```
052 Chair 1200 100 30 2
096 Cabinet 15000 80 40 85
182 Table 1600 60 60 70
163 Mirror 25800 120 60 70
149 Desk 3650 180 100 5
077 Bookshelf 5000 120 30 80
146 Cupboard 9000 80 60 200
ID Name Weight Length With Height
```

Where it just seems to sort by first and second digit resulting in 15000 being put as smaller than 1600

How can i solve these problems in the best way?

Comment: Amazing how your data looks almost identical to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227463/how-to-use-sort-command-in-batch-and-sort-over-9) that was just asked yesterday.

Comment: Two issues: 1. You have to exclude the headline from sorting using the option `skip=1` for `for /F`; to get it for the output, use `< %file% (set "HL=" & set /P HL="")` and do `echo(%HL%` later. 2. `sort` sorts alphabetically but what you need is alpha-numerical sorting; to achieve that you have to temporarily pad numbers with zeros to the left for them to consist of the same number of digits, then you can alphabetical order equals alpha-numerical order. *N. B.:* You do not need the `par#` variables, neither do you need delayed expansion; just use: `echo(%%C %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F`…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the actual help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably accomplish your task like in the following script (see all the explanatory remarks):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"                      & rem // (file with data to be sorted)
set "_SCOL=3"                        & rem // (number of column to sort)
set "_ANUM=#"                        & rem // (alpha-numeric sorting if not empty)
set "_DESC="                         & rem // (descending order if not empty)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
rem // Gather TAB character:
for /F "delims=" %%T in ('
    forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo/0x09"
') do set "_TAB=%%T"

rem // Read first line of file into variable:
< "%_FILE%" (set "HEAD=" & set /P HEAD="") || exit /B
rem // Write to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Read all but first line from file line by line:
    for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
        rem // Store current line string:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Extract sort token from current line:
        for /F "tokens=%_SCOL% delims=%_TAB% eol=%_TAB%" %%K in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Store sort token string:
            set "ITEM=%%K"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Check if alpha-numeric sorting is desired:
            if defined _ANUM (
                rem // Check whether sort token only consists of decimal figures:
                (for /F "delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%Z in ("!ITEM!") do rem/) || (
                    rem // Zero-pad sort token to the left up to 12 digits:
                    set "ITEM=000000000000!ITEM!" & set "ITEM=!ITEM:~-12!"
                )
            )
            rem // Write (padded) sort token plus delimter plus line string:
            echo(!ITEM!%_TAB%!LINE!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
rem // Prepare sort option:
if defined _DESC (set "SOPT=/R") else set "SOPT="
rem // Copy first line, do sorting, strip off sort token, write remainder:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=%_TAB% eol=%_TAB%" %%K in ('
    cmd /V /C echo(_!_TAB!!HEAD!^& rem/ ^& ^
        sort %SOPT% "%_TMPF%"
') do echo(%%L
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

The path/name of the text file needs to be provided as a command line argument.

Comment: Hey man, I got a remark on the exercise and that was that it needs to handle a two part name like "White Desk". In shell i solved it by putting a tab between every column and then using tab as a delim in the sort command. Is there a simple modify to this code to solve it in batch aswell?

Comment: Alright, I adapted the script; before _tabs_ and _spaces_ were used as delimiters, now only _tab_ is used…